# JMX Spring connect to localhost without specifying the server address and port

Tags: java, spring, jmx, spring-jmx

I am referring here

```
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html#jmx-proxy
```

I am trying to connect to localhost MBeanServer and perform some operation using Spring Proxy.
The problem is just specifying the ObjectName and ProxyInterface, I am unable to connect to localhost. I am able to solve this problem by specifying the server property of the MBeanProxyFactoryBean.

Here is my spring `context.xml`

```
bean id="proxyWithoutServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.access.MBeanProxyFactoryBean"
          p:objectName="com.xxx.yyy"
          p:proxyInterface="com.MyInterface" 

bean id="proxyWithServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.access.MBeanProxyFactoryBean"
          p:objectName="com.xxx.yyy"
          p:proxyInterface="com.MyInterface" 
p:server-ref="clientConnector"

<bean id="clientConnector" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean"
          p:serviceUrl="service:jmx:rmi://localhost/jndi/rmi://localhost:8001/jmxrmi" />
```

In Java code, I simply do

```
MyInterface myInterface = context.getBean("proxyWithoutServer");
myInterface.myMethod();
```

But this doesnt work. - Says Unable to connect to localhost

But If I use

```
MyInterface myInterface = context.getBean("proxyWithServer");
myInterface.myMethod();
```

This works.

The problem here is that this code would be run on multiple servers and the jmx port in each would be different. SO I would not want to specify the port number. Hence I would like 
the proxyWithoutServer version of this to work.
Looking at the spring jmx documentation it seems we do not need to specify the server port if we are trying to connect to local MBean Server.
Would need some advice on what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a local reference to the MBeanServer.

```
<context:mbean-server id="localMBeanServer"/>
```

Then use `localMBeanServer` in the p:server-ref.

Comment: Tried this. I am getting InvalidInvocationError.

Comment: I just ran a test and it worked fine for me; you must have something mis-configured.